# meta urls on the error page leading to a non-exist page

Tags: bug, status-completed

In the error page: 
https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/

Both meta links (in the body and in the bottom) are referring to this url: `http://meta.prowebmasters.stackexchange.com`

Edit: now the link in the body points to: http://http//meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com